# Deleting the contents from common columns dataframe based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with 8 columns. Some rows only differ in certain columns. I would like to delete the contents for the repeated materials. Let's say columns C1 and C2 are the keys and column C3, C4 are the values for one set C5 and c6 are the values for another set
here is what I have

```
|C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6|
|A |C |E |F |H |I |
|A |C |E |F |H |J |
|B |D |E |F |H |I |
|B |D |E |G |H |I |
```

here is what I want

```
|C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6|
|A |C |E |F |H |I |
|  |  |  |  |H |J |
|B |D |E |F |H |I |
|  |  |E |G |  |  |
```

Comment: My mistake, Changed the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most elegant way but it should work.

```
import pandas as pd 

data = [['C1','C2','C3','C4','C5','C6'],
['A' ,'C' ,'E' ,'F' ,'H' ,'I'], 
['A' ,'C' ,'E' ,'F' ,'H','J'],
['B' ,'D' ,'E' ,'F' ,'H' ,'I'],
['B' ,'D','E','G' ,'H','I']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:])
df.columns = data[0]

new_data = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index == 0:
        pass
    else:
        current_row = df.iloc[index]
        last_row = df.iloc[index-1]
        new_row = []
        if [last_row['C1'], last_row['C2']] != [current_row['C1'], current_row['C2']]:
             new_row.append([current_row['C1'], current_row['C2']])
        else:
            new_row.append(['', ''])
        if  [last_row['C3'], last_row['C4']] != [current_row['C3'], current_row['C4']]:
            new_row.append([current_row['C3'], current_row['C4']])
        else:
            new_row.append(['', ''])
        if  [last_row['C5'], last_row['C6']] != [current_row['C5'], current_row['C6']]:
            new_row.append([current_row['C5'], current_row['C6']])
        else:
            new_row.append(['', ''])
        new_data.append([item for sublist in new_row for item in sublist])

print (pd.DataFrame(new_data))
```

Comment: What if I had three rows that contain the same key? or four rows?

Comment: You might want to adjust the three consecutive if-statements and evaluatie df.iloc[index-2] and df.iloc[index-3] etc...